# What distinguishes .new from .new(true)? "Indent" XML document in Test-First-Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working through these problems and am a little stuck on how to finish this out.  This is the RSPEC and what's specifically troubling me is the last "it indents" test:

```
# # Topics
#
# * method_missing
# * blocks
# * strings
# * hashes

require "13_xml_document"

describe XmlDocument do
  before do
    @xml = XmlDocument.new
  end

  it "renders an empty tag" do
    @xml.hello.should == "<hello/>"
  end

  it "renders a tag with attributes" do
    @xml.hello(:name => 'dolly').should == "<hello name='dolly'/>"
  end

  it "renders a randomly named tag" do
    tag_name = (1..8).map{|i| ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)]}.join
    @xml.send(tag_name).should == "<#{tag_name}/>"
  end

  it "renders block with text inside" do
    @xml.hello do
      "dolly"
    end.should == "<hello>dolly</hello>"
  end

  it "nests one level" do
    @xml.hello do
      @xml.goodbye
    end.should == "<hello><goodbye/></hello>"
  end

  it "nests several levels" do
    xml = XmlDocument.new
    xml.hello do
      xml.goodbye do
        xml.come_back do
          xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
        end
      end
    end.should == "<hello><goodbye><come_back><ok_fine be='that_way'/></come_back></goodbye></hello>"
  end

  it "indents" do
    @xml = XmlDocument.new(true)
    @xml.hello do
      @xml.goodbye do
        @xml.come_back do
          @xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
        end
      end
    end.should ==
    "<hello>\n" +
    "  <goodbye>\n" +
    "    <come_back>\n" +
    "      <ok_fine be='that_way'/>\n" +
    "    </come_back>\n" +
    "  </goodbye>\n" +
    "</hello>\n"
  end
end
```

I feel like I understand the problem and the solution would be something like

```
"<#{method}>\n" + "  #{yield}" + "</#{method}>\n"
```

given my code:

```
    class XmlDocument
#use method missing so that arbitrary methods 
#can be called and converted to XML

    def method_missing(method, hash=nil, &block)
         if (hash == nil && block == nil)
             "<#{method}/>"
         elsif hash.is_a?(Hash)
             #renders tag with attributes (from hash)

             my_key = nil
             my_val = nil
             hash.each do |key, value|
                 my_key = key
                 my_val = value
             end
             "<#{method} #{my_key}='#{my_val}'/>"
         else
             #passes whatever to between tags including nested methods.

             "<#{method}>#{yield}</#{method}>"
         end
    end

end
```

My problem is  **I don't know how to distinguish the "it nests several levels" test from the "it indents" test** so I can fit it into my "if" statement.  The only thing that seems to distinguish them is the the "it indents" test has

```
@xml = XmlDocument.new(true)
```

What does it mean to have "true" as an argument of #new? Is it relevant to my problem?

Comment: It is hard to say what distinguishes the 2 since we don't know what the initialize method for `XmlDocument` looks like. Also I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with this method_missing but i think you mis understand how `#each` works as you are just overwriting `my_key` and `my_val` for every element in the `Hash`

Comment: From the specs you post, passing true to new changes the output to be indented with each tag on a newline

Comment: Thanks @FrederickCheung, I guess my question is: how do I fit this knowledge into the general scheme of my "if" statement? how would I set up an additional "elsif" for when true is passed through new? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to behave differently every time you emit text (since you'll need to add new lines and spaces to line things up) and probably also track what the current indentation level is, so you know how many spaces to prepend.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an argument to the object when it is initialized.  In this case, you want the value to default to `false`.  This way, the code for indents only runs when `XmlDocument.new(true)` is called.

```
class XmlDocument
    def initialize(indent = false)
        @indent = indent
    end

    def method_missing(method, args=nil, &block)
        if @indent == true
            #run with indents
        else
            #run without indents
        end
    end
end
```